# How to convert this stored procedure into HQL Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate

I have a stored procedure that I have to convert it into Nhibernate create query. Procedure has a CASE clause. Procedure is:

```
Select * From tDRMaster  
 Where fDate =  
    Case When @Date IS NULL Then (Select Max(fDate) From tDRMaster Where fPropertyID = @PropertyID)  
    Else @Date  
   End  
   And fPropertyID = @PropertyID
```

Comment: is hql a requirement or is QueryOver an option

Comment: hql or create criteria is requirement.

Comment: This is rather too broad for Stack Overflow - while the question contains code, it is a "plz convert this code for me", which these days we try to discourage. I don't know if it would have been on-topic in 2013 `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = session.CreateCriteria<DrMaster>()
    .Add(Expression.EqProperty("fDate",
        Projections.Conditional(Expression.Eq("Date", null), 
            Projections.SubQuery(DetachedCriteria.For<DrMaster>()
                .Add(Expression.EqProperty("fPropertyId", "PropertyId"))
                .SetProjection(Projections.Max("fDate"))),
            Projections.Property("Date"))))
    .Add(Expression.EqProperty("fPropertyId", "PropertyId"))
    .List<DrMaster>();
```